# Setting current tab dynamically WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I'm working on some feature for my IDE, clicking some treeviewitem, will change the current displayed tab. I'm trying to do that, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?
How can I set the desired tab to be focued?

Here's the code:

```
        void tr_ViewOtherClass(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            string tagToView = ((TreeViewItem) sender).Tag.ToString();
            TabItem currentTab = ((TabItem) (tabControl.SelectedItem));
            if (tagToView != currentTab.Tag.ToString())
            {
                TabItem tabToView = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < tabControl.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    tabToView = ((TabItem) (tabControl.Items[i]));
                    if (tabToView.Tag.ToString() == tagToView)
                        break;
                }
                classCodes[currentTab.Tag.ToString()] = ((TextEditor) currentTab.Content).Text;
                currentTab = tabToView;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wrong mindset. a `TabControl` conceptually is a `Selector` of `Views`, in which only one `View` is active at the time. WPF works best with the MVVM mentality, than with the traditional `manipulate-visual-elements-in-code-behind` mentality.

Comment: @HighCore Can you give me any code sample for how dealing with such things please?

Comment: http://tap-source.com/mvvm-tabcontrol/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a value to the `currentTab` variable, it **does not** modify `tabControl.SelectedItem`.

You must assign directly `tabControl.SelectedItem` if you want to change its value ; `currentTab` is equivalent to a pointer, and modifying its value only modifies the value pointed by the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

TabItem currentTab
and
TabItem tabToView
Are each just local variables.
You need to have  tabControl SelectedItem bound two way with notify if you want to push the change to the UI.

TabControl behaves differently in MVVM.
I gave the non MVVM way.
MVVM is probably a better way to go for this.